# Adding to <head> at runtime but it adds to <body>

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to add content to the `<head>` at runtime. The content is free text supplied by the user, which may or may not be a valid HTML tag (I know this is dangerous but that's my task).

The content is added but for some unknown reason it's added to the `<body>`.

I've tried the following:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="HtmlHeadTagInsert" />

HtmlHeadTagInsert.Text = "custom text"
```

and:

```
Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, New LiteralControl("custom text"))
```

This is an ASP.NET Master Page using VB.NET

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does the `<head>` tag have a `runat="server"` attribute? Is your code in the code-behind for the master page or the content page?

Comment: runat="server", yes. Code-behind for master page.

Comment: "...which may or may not be a valid HTML tag." Is it a tag that belongs in the head? When are you adding it? On a postback? Need more info, exactly how you're trying to do it.